# Is there a way to automatically resolve an overloaded method via a template parameter?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I was trying to write a general purpose method locking wrapper for operations around a list. What I currently have is:

```
template <typename OP, typename... ARGS>
auto locked_call (OP op, ARGS... args) const
-> decltype(op(args...)) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g(lock_);
    return op(args...);
}
```

And, I can use it like this:

```
auto push_back = [this](decltype(p) p) {
    return list_.push_back(p); };
locked_call(push_back, p);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZFPa8QgEMXv@ykGejGQDe11kwo99bhLeywluCpZWU0kjktLyWdP1Wz@lM5Jee/N/By5tfuG8/FBtVx7IaHSyiHdrXfjUX7R0WHvOYLhNwk/OwgVBHbWEhyKwyGmKtUihXiqy/@O1Ad0x69BTTJKYzXDMAO/rWyZkXA85TBfiqKAl7fXd5rMzGOX0lLUnGkN5HiCzubJEq2sb1wGvGsdpsCegpBcx26ksyTKwZZld/pYE3kkajzrRbVyUmhIErJycfcSfd/CptekDdNrbp0SwIQAEtYAdjsnsVvvLvWZ8Ss8wwdelPskC19w/wlsxqV1Fks4WEsYVqjNRshiykO3mS14dxHIMNUCiZDzoPSV5v5TRSAnT48hNozjLw)

But, I would rather be able to pass the method to be called directly into `locked_call` and it dispatch directly against `list_`.

```
template <typename METHOD, typename... ARGS>
auto locked_call (METHOD op, ARGS... args) const
-> decltype((list_.*op)(args...)) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g(lock_);
    return (list_.*op)(args...);
}
```

I realized quickly this is tricky because of method overloading, and research seems to indicate explicitly resolving the overload is required.

```
locked_call(static_cast<void (List::*)(const int &)>(&List::push_back), p);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHBasMwDL3nKwSDYpc23a5JMeyyXTZatg8oru1lpk5iYqdsjH57Jivt2o76YGzpvacnSXk/r5Qa7myjXK8NLJ0NUWTnf91H8yWyLH57o80HhKiLIoGWtokCXvBVXieJAa/pLocQu15FqNXewE8GeDAtt84QE5LQpryKExFcq3aYoEw0tXcyoplUp5G1gdV6BqdPnufw@Pb8Lggs@9gS2@iNks4BW62h9TOCJKjsqsBBtU2IRJgL0Ea5pMYY@cmnrecs4RDP@dF3OmPzyVrVy04vyauAilGMl3/AzsS@a@CW3gg6jK3tW6tBag0Mpwn@stZFDyxEGa3CN46dKCxNryimnFEjkNgTLthkjPs@fG62Uu34DEXPthaLS9X/YMIi5klaF44uD7iDLKnX0mI/qfjJJO20Pi4vxybYwz3WOgzDLw)

Is there any clever use of templates or `decltype` I can use to allow the code to simply pass the method name into `locked_call`?

---

As a hack, I can use a macro to achieve the simplified syntax by autogenerating a lambda:

```
#define LOCKED_CALL(METHOD, ...) \
    locked_call([this,##__VA_ARGS__](){ \
        return list_.METHOD(__VA_ARGS__); })
```

But I was hoping there was a template equivalent.

Comment: Can you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: what is `list_` ?

Comment: @Jans: Link to Try It Online provided.

Comment: Why not resolve it at call site ? `locked_call([&](){ return list_.method(arg1, arg2);})`

Comment: @Jarod42: The macro version does basically that. I am asking about passing in the method.

Comment: Not sure if I understand. Does `std::invoke` not do exactly what you want except the lock? So you could copy the implementation of std::invoke and add add your locking to that copy?

Comment: @PatrickFromberg: It seems to not be able to resolve the overload either.

Comment: Ah, yes, now that Yakk sent his answer I start to understand the question 8-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be explicit about which overload you want to use.

You can replace the `static_cast` with template parameters:

```
template <typename R, typename... ARGS>
R locked_call (R (List::*op)(ARGS...), ARGS... args) const {
    std::lock_guard<Mutex> g(lock_);
    return (list_.*op)(args...);
}

void add (int p) {
    locked_call<void, const int &>(&List::push_back, p);
}
```

Or, you can simply use a local variable to resolve the ambiguity:

```
template <typename OP, typename... ARGS>
auto locked_call (OP op, ARGS... args) const -> decltype((list_.*op)(args...)) {
    std::lock_guard<Mutex> g(lock_);
    return (list_.*op)(args...);
}

void add (int p) {
    void (List::*m)(const int &) = &List::push_back;
    locked_call(m, p);
}
```

Comment: So there is no way to tell a template to resolve the overload for you, even if you are providing the template with the types of the parameters that will be passed to the method?

Comment: @jxh short answer - no. You have to manually help it a little.

Comment: Another problem I seem to be running into is that default parameters are not treated as an overload of the method with fewer parameters. Does this mean that if I am trying to call such a method, I have to supply what the default parameter would have been explicitly?

Comment: "*default parameters are not treated as an overload of the method with fewer parameters*" - no, they are not. A parameter is part of the method's signature, but a parameter **value** is not. It does not matter if a parameter has a default value or not, that is just syntax sugar for the benefit of coders. The parameter itself still exists whether a default value is provided or not. That is what is important. "*Does this mean that if I am trying to call such a method, I have to supply what the default parameter would have been explicitly?*" - when calling it through a pointer-to-method, yes.

Comment: So I could coerce "implicit" resolution for `push_back` by changing your first `locked_call` to pass `const ARGS&...`  in the signature to the `op` parameter. However, `erase` seems to be implemented with a default value for the second parameter rather than as a single parameter method.

Comment: "*However, `erase` seems to be implemented with a default value for the second parameter rather than as a single parameter method*" - [no, it is not](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase). There are no default-valued parameters, but there are overloads for different parameter counts.

Comment: You are right, I was confused by a different error message. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZLPTsMwDMbvfQpLSFPKuo5d21GJExe4dA8wZUlWqiVt1KQTCO3VKXY69kdw2IEcoiT@Pvvn1sLaWSXEcFc3QvdSwVLXzhfR@W56r96LKPIfVkm1BedllpFoWTe@gBc85dfB4IBX2vPB@a4XHozYK/iMABeG@Uar4ARKtM6v3oMRdCt2GAgRr4zV3CMM1Wm4UVAmcDo/lc9F0JXBpeRacK2BlcCoRpbdtzZmqIoT0gLvqhhE22D5kYjW2BYVrXreyWWgKKBi4S3OT8JO@b5rgAXyNKSmhKPgcAtwmqbEsboBeqQk8QRdI/@K/FjS/XsTjmpcNbJvawlcSmD4s8HGF7UuqNlkRLa9e1tvuNglKP2dx7YW2G/oPxKpjjuVjMORblRVNyw@JzzgWETEY3iNPVDuH7AwZuY4TymCs8XD0TifmxQJGF4Pw/AltppXbpjhJ3sU0@li8Q0 "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: If I change the `pop` call to use `cbegin()` instead, it works.

Answer (score 3):

```
#define RETURNS(...) \
  noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__)) \
  ->decltype(__VA_ARGS__) \
  { return __VA_ARGS__; }

#define OVERLOADS_OF(...) \
  [](auto&&...args) \
  RETURNS( __VA_ARGS__( decltype(args)(args)... ) )

#define METHOD(...) \
  [](auto&& self, auto&&...args) \
  RETURNS((decltype(self)(self).* __VA_ARGS__)( decltype(args)(args)... ) )
```

We can then do:

```
locked_call(METHOD(&List::push_back), list, p);
```

and it should work.

This requires [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) support.

Or:

```
#define OVERLOADS_OF(...) \
  [&](auto&&...args) \
  RETURNS( __VA_ARGS__( decltype(args)(args)... ) )
```

would let you do

```
locked_call(OVERLOADS_OF(list.push_back), p);
```

Comment: Cool, I knew I wasn't the only one that wrote complicated macros in C++ :-)

Comment: Can you use the lambda automatic return type deduction to return the address of the resolved method, rather than the result of calling the method? This is so I can use the second form of `locked_call`.

Comment: @jsh Not in the way you are asking, no.